# Is this a good design?

Tags: c++

Right now, I'm making a Gui Library for games. The Widgets have several callbacks / listeners for various events.

The thing about it is a listener can consume an event.

The issue comes here. The base class is called with event info. It calls the callbacks for the listeners. Any of them can handle the event.

This means it is up to the user to check if the event has been handled or not.

Ex:

```
void TextBox::MouseClick(MouseEvent &event)
{
   Widget::MouseClick(event);

    if(!event.isHandled())
    {
       //do stuff
    }

}
```

The alternative would be to hide this and have onMouseClick(...) which is the virtual one and not called unless the condition is met. I found this to be rather messy though, and annoying for those who make more events.

Is this a good design? If not what might be better to accommodate this?

Thanks

Comment: Which one do you want to know if is good design?  Your quoted code segment is a pretty normal way to go about it.  You might find the 'higherarchal visitor' (check google) to be interesting...maybe..

Comment: well I prefer the former since the latter, onMouseClick() seems messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to this for many events, I'd rather go the `onMouseClick` way (IIUC):

```
void TextBox::onMouseClick(MouseEvent &event)
{
       //do stuff or empty of not needed
}
```

in class Widget:

```
void Widget::MouseClick(MouseEvent &event) // nonvirtual
{
  // do the listeners' stuff
  if(event.isHandled()) onMouseClick(event);
}
```